# twitteR data & ggplot2 – how to plot lat long of US ONLY

Tags: r, ggplot2, twitter-streaming-api

I've spent about 5 - 6 hours searching the web on how to only display lat lon US data on my map. Currently, I have lat lon points from all over the world... what I want to do is only display points in the US.

Also, I'm new to R and have been learning through hacking code together for a week. Therefore, if anyone can also point be to some good tutorials or lessons for R, I would really appreciate it.

```
# Create happy Database
register_sqlite_backend("happy_tweets.db")
search_twitter_and_store('#happy', table_name = "tweets", lang = NULL,  locale = NULL, retryOnRateLimit = 120)
happy_tweets <- load_tweets_db(as.data.frame = TRUE, table_name = "tweets")

# Create sad Database
register_sqlite_backend("sad_tweets.db")
search_twitter_and_store('#sad', table_name = "tweets", lang = NULL,  locale = NULL, retryOnRateLimit = 120)
sad_tweets <- load_tweets_db(as.data.frame = TRUE, table_name = "tweets")

###########

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
map.data <- map_data("world")

#extract lat and long only
happy_points <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(happy_tweets$lon), y = as.numeric(happy_tweets$lat), 
                           text = as.character(happy_tweets$text), screenName = as.character(happy_tweets$screenName))
sad_points <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(sad_tweets$lon), y = as.numeric(sad_tweets$lat), 
                         t = as.character(sad_tweets$text), screenName = as.character(sad_tweets$screenName))

# remove empty values
happy_points <- happy_points[rowSums(is.na(happy_points)) == 0,]
sad_points <- sad_points[rowSums(is.na(sad_points)) == 0,]

## plot on map
ggplot(map.data) + geom_map(aes(map_id = region), map = map.data, fill = "white", color = "grey70", size = 0.20) + 
        expand_limits(x = map.data$long, y = map.data$lat) + theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(0 * c(-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5), "lines")) + 
        geom_point(data = happy_points, aes(x = x, y = y), size = .3, alpha = 2/10, color = "blue") +
        geom_point(data = sad_points, aes(x = x, y = y), size = .3, alpha = 4/10, color = "red")
```

Generates (image):
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6144462/24273962/a34b188c-0fe2-11e7-8df6-972b3fcc84a2.png

**If I limit my map_data to `states` map visually only shows US, but it's small and still displays all points outside US**

Generages (image):
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6144462/24273918/53ce2e52-0fe2-11e7-9763-52a363805966.png

Thanks in advance.